# How to record a video in iOS app after device locked?

Tags: ios, swift, video-capture, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I am currently working on iOS app which allows user to record a video. I am stuck at the point when device locked/ screen goes off, that time video recording stops. I want to continue recording after device locked. Is that possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can disable the built-in idle timer to prevent the device from going to sleep by setting

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

while you're recording.

Comment: Thanks @Gereon. I wonder how some other apps like Spycam, etc., are doing this kind of recording?